# If $H$ and $K$ are solvable subgroups of $G$ with $H\unlhd G $ then $HK$ is a solvable subgroup of $G .$

Tags: proof-verification, solvable-groups

> If $H$ and $K$ are solvable subgroups of $G$ with $H\unlhd G $ then $HK$ is a solvable subgroup of $G .$

**Here is my proof :**

Now if we can show the quotient group $\displaystyle\frac{HK}{H}$ and $H$ are both solvable then so is $HK .$

So now the only task is to prove that this quotient group $~\displaystyle\frac{K}{H\cap K}~$ is actually solvable .

Note that $H\unlhd G$ and $H\subseteq HK $ which implies that   $ H\unlhd HK\le G .$ Then by second isomorphism theorem for groups to give

$$\frac{HK}{H}\cong \frac{K}{H\cap K} ~.$$

Then the quotient group $\displaystyle\frac{K}{H\cap K}$ is solvable since it is the homomorphic image of the solvable group $K$ if we consider the natural projection $\varphi:K\longrightarrow\displaystyle\frac{K}{H\cap K}~.$

Is there anyone to check my working for validity ? Any advice will be appreciated . Thanks for patient reading .

Comment: Your proof is fine.